# How to access variable in for loop

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am experimenting with for loops and so far have this -

```
echo off
set "projectPath=%~1\Translations\"

echo projectPath %projectPath%

cd %projectPath%

set "tmp=f"
for /r %%g in (*.ts) do (
    echo %%g
    set %tmp%="www"
    echo %tmp%
)
```

When run tmp is 'f' and I dont know why

Please could someone explain what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

```
echo projectPath %projectPath%

cd %projectPath%
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "tmp=f"
for /r %%g in (*.ts) do (
    echo %%g
    set %tmp%="www"
    echo !tmp!
)
endlocal
```

Delayed expansion is one of most confusing things related to batch scripting.  For more info check the links bellow.

[link1](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

[link2](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/variableexpansion.php)

[link3](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/08/23/714650.aspx)